# Question on Cauchy problem on manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, lorentzian-geometry, cauchy-problem

Let $(M,g)$ be a globally-hyperbolic manifold, i.e. $M=\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma$ and $g=-\beta^2 \, dt^2+h_{t}$. Furthermore, let $E$ be a vector bundle over $M$ and $\square$ a normally-hyperbolic operator. Then, it is a well-known result that the Cauchy problem

$$\begin{cases}\square u=f\\u\vert_\Sigma = u_0 \\ \nabla_n u\vert_\Sigma = u_1 \end{cases}$$

has a unique solution $u\in\Gamma(E)$ for suitable Cauchy data $(f,u_{0},u_{1})$. My question is the following:

> What exactly does $u\vert_\Sigma$ mean in this context?

The point is, there are two possible interpretation and I cannot see which one it is. In order to explain myself, let me restrict to a specific situation: As a bundle we take $E=T^{\ast}M$ and as an operator the Hodge operator $\square=d \delta+\delta d$. So, our space objects is the space of $1$-forms $\omega\in\Omega^1(M)$. Let us write $\omega=\omega_0 \, d t+\omega_1$, where $\omega_0:=\omega(\partial_t)$ and $\omega_1:=\omega-\omega_0 \, d t$ is a $t$-dependent $1$-form on $\Sigma$.

> Now, when writing $\omega\vert_\Sigma$, to I have to specify both
> $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$ at $t=0$, or just $\omega_1$?

EDIT: My confusion comes from the following fact: Usually, people write that the space of initial data is $u_0,u_1 \in\Gamma(\Sigma,E)$, i.e. sections of the subbundle $E\vert_\Sigma$. In our case, this subbundle is $T^\ast \Sigma\vert_\Sigma \cong\underline{\Sigma}\oplus T^\ast\Sigma$, i.e. it includes both initial data for $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$. On the other hand, the notation $\omega\vert_\Sigma$ looks more like $i^\ast \omega$ with $i^\ast:\Sigma\to M$ being the embedding, which is equivalent to $i^\ast\omega=\omega_1\vert_{t=0}$, so just initial data for $\omega_1$.

Comment: You need both $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$, otherwise the result is false. This confusion is only possible when $E$ is a bundle of $k$-forms ($1$-forms in your example). It would be very strange if the notion of (Cauchy) initial data were to suddenly change for forms, compared to all other bundles.